# How to set second step as active step in Material-2 stepper?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

```
<mat-vertical-stepper>
<mat-step label="Agreement Preparation">
    <p>Agreement preparion is intiated by our side </p>
</mat-step>
<mat-step label="Ready for Biometric" selected active>
    <p>Agreement preparion is intiated by our side </p>

</mat-step>
<mat-step label="Document in Submission">
    <p>Agreement preparion is intiated by our side </p>

</mat-step>
```

i tried setting active and selected but it does not work.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Add a reference to your stepper e.g. `#stepper` and after the view initializes, set the `selectedIndex` of `stepper` to 1.

**In your Template:**

```html
        <mat-vertical-stepper #stepper>
            <mat-step label="Agreement Preparation">
                <p>Agreement preparion is intiated by our side </p>
            </mat-step>
            <mat-step label="Ready for Biometric">
                <p>Agreement preparion is intiated by our side </p>
            </mat-step>
            <mat-step label="Document in Submission">
                <p>Agreement preparion is intiated by our side </p>
            </mat-step>
        </mat-vertical-stepper>
```

**... and in your Typescript:**

```js
    import { ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { MatStepper } from '@angular/material';
    
    Component({
        .....
    })
    export class ComponentClass implements AfterViewInit {
        @ViewChild('stepper') stepper: MatStepper;
        
        ngAfterViewInit() {
            this.stepper.selectedIndex = 1; 
        }
    }
```

Link to [**StackBlitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mat-beta-12-luhe7n?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: You forgot `...implements AfterViewInit` :)

Comment: @developer033 , that doesn't matter, its only necessary to write for tooling purpose. The code still runs fine without it :)

Comment: Yes, we all know that this code runs fine without `implements`. It's just a question of preference and about follow the standards. Regards :)

Comment: @Faisal How can we change the icon for Completed step... by default it is material icon 'create' ...is there option to change it to some other material icon name ...like 'done' ?

Comment: I think there is a feature request for that on github. Saw it a couple of days ago. Maybe in the next release its available. I'll try to find the link.

Comment: i referred the code here https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/stepper/stepper-vertical.html ... it says _getIndicatorType ...is it internal api or can we use it ?

Comment: It is internal ... you should be able to set `icon` for `mat-step-header` as input according to the link i posted in comment above

Comment: @Faisal i tried setting icon for mat-step-header like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mat-beta-12-zsenh5 ,...but i dont know where to add reference in html ...i added to <md-step> and it didnt work

Comment: Additional Info - if you use `linear="true"` then make use it is set to false (this work), or omitted altogether (not tested).

Answer (score 13):

For anyone still viewing this, this is how I did it without implementing `AfterViewInit`.

```html
    <div *ngIf="!processing">
        <mat-vertical-stepper linear [selectedIndex]="currentStep">
            <mat-step label="Step 1">Step 1</mat-step>
            <mat-step label="Step 2">Step 2</mat-step>
            <mat-step label="Step 3">Step 3</mat-step>
            <mat-step label="Step 4">Step 4</mat-step>
        </mat-vertical-stepper>
    </div>
```

My ts file:

```js
    ngOnInit() {
        this.processing = true;
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.currentStep = 2;
          this.processing = false;
        }, 1500);
    }
```

This `setTimeout()` is used to simulate an api call that takes some time. This helps you show the stepper only when you're sure you know which index  you would like to set active.

Comment: I find this approach cleaner and simpler in some quick use cases.. In template, just assign the number of the index of the steps, say, `[selectedIndex]="1"` (will select 2nd stepper) and you're good to go.

Answer (score 5):

Use attribut `selectedIndex` in mat-horizontal-stepper for default

Ex:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear" #stepper selectedIndex="2">
  <mat-label></mat-label>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Note: start index with 0 (ZERO)